# how to make the 2 pagination dots with square space (not parent's width) in the middle?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I used [this](http://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/need-to-create-an-onboarding-flow-for-your-mobile-app-heres-how-to-do-it-using-uipageviewcontroller-in-swift/) tutorial to create a tutorial to my swift app.

Here is my code

https://gist.github.com/elad2109/105ed78c544fe83e8a56

Here is my result

[image]

how can I make the 2 dots in the middle?

[image]

Comment: It seems in your second screen shot that the entire content is off to the left, not just the dots.

Comment: i want the dots to be integral part of the screen not a bottom bar. I didn't get your note

Comment: Re: "how can I make the 2 dots in the middle?"... the entire layout is off center, so you might want to align the entire thing — if that's what you mean by "middle".